# Python logging add filter for handler in ini file?

Tags: python, logging, filter

I have a log.ini like this:

```
[handler_info]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=fmt
filter=infofilter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_error]
class=StreamHandler
level=ERROR
filter=errorfilter
formatter=fmt
args=(sys.stdout,)

[filter_infofilter]
class=util.testfm.InfoFilter

[filter_errorfilter]
class=util.testfm.ErrorFilter
```

But it dosen't work. And I don't want to dynamic add filter for the handler like `handler.addFilter(logging.Filter('foo'))`

My filter like this:

```
class InfoFilter(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, rec):
        return rec.levelno <= logging.INFO


class ErrorFilter(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, rec):
        return rec.levelno > logging.INFO
```

What I want to achieve?  I want to use one logger and two different handler to write different level log into different files.

I aslo find  " If you need to have instances of Filter in your logging configuration, you will need to use dictConfig() " in https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seem like I can only do something like:

```
class InfoHandler(StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        StreamHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.addFilter(InfoFilter())


class ErrorHandler(StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        StreamHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.addFilter(ErrorFilter())
```

add make ini like :

```
[handler_error]
class=misc.testfm.ErrorHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ErrorFilter` filters out log records that have level `INFO` and lower, so it basically sets the lower threshold to, despite its name, level `WARNING` (which is the next level after `INFO`).

For the lower threshold the `level` field for a handler should work:

```
[handler_error]
class=StreamHandler
level=WARNING
```

`InfoFilter`, on the other hand, sets the upper threshold for a log record level. That's when you need to make a custom handler:

```
class InfoHandler(StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InfoHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.addFilter(InfoFilter())
```

And configure the handler to use your class:

```
[handler_info]
class=misc.testfm.InfoHandler
```